# Lexical <![CDATA[]]> is not getting detected by MXXML2.IVBSAXLexicalHandler_startCDATA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, sax

I am trying to handle Large XML file thru SAXON library in VBA

**Source XML** has following tag

```xml
<Id><![CDATA[IPMS_TEST_DS_2 & 13]]></Id>
```

**Destination XML** while writing into a destination file if am getting following xml tag

```xml
<Id>IPMS_TEST_DS_2 &amp; 13</Id> <!--- This should be as same as parent XML -->
```

by implementing **SAXXMLReader60** as reader & **MXXMLWriter60** as writer
(Source : [FlyLib.com](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.378.1.61/1/), [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa926344%28v%3Dmsdn.10%29) )

```vb
Implements IVBSAXContentHandler
Implements SAXXMLReader60
Implements IVBSAXLexicalHandler
Implements IVBSAXDTDHandler

Private rdr As New SAXXMLReader60
Private wrt As New MXXMLWriter60

Private ch As IVBSAXContentHandler
Private dtdh As IVBSAXDTDHandler
Private lexh As IVBSAXLexicalHandler

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set ch = wrt 
    Set dtdh = wrt

    Call rdr.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", wrt)
    Set lexh = wrt

End Sub

'....Following Event handlers are not getting triggered...

Private Sub IVBSAXLexicalHandler_comment(strChars As String)
End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXLexicalHandler_endCDATA()
    lexh.endCDATA
End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXLexicalHandler_endDTD()
End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXLexicalHandler_endEntity(strName As String)
End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXLexicalHandler_startCDATA()
    lexh.startCDATA
End Sub
```

Please suggest way to detect *< ![CDATA[]]>* while reading

Comment: Is the reference to "Saxon" library to the Saxon 9 XSLT 2/3 processor by Saxonica? Are you using XSLT to try to create a CDATA section in the `Id` element? On the XSLT side you would need `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="Id"/>` to achieve that, if the XSLT processor is in charge of the serialization.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, XML file is such huge that I cannot load in memory as XML & fire XQuery/use XSLT for modifying Source XML. Hence, I am using SAXONReader of **MSXML2** for reading XML line by line & writing XML using MXXMLWriter of same library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many iterations over various options, I got to know the correct method of calling *SAXReader.putProperty*

It catches CDATA for writing into destination XML

**Main Code Block**

```vb
Sub Main()
     Dim saxRdr As New SAXXMLReader60
     Dim evntHndlr As New SAXEventHandlerClass

     Set saxRdr.contentHandler = evntHndlr
     Call saxRdr.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", evntHndlr.wrt)
     '......above line makes event IVBSAXContentHandler_characters(strChars As String) to catch CDATA tag as it is......

     saxRdr.parseURL "test.xml"

     Set saxRdr = Nothing
End sub
```

**SAXEventHandlerClass**: *characters* event catches CDATA Lexical automatically into *strChars*

```vb
Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_characters(strChars As String)
     'content writer logic goes here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is not part of the XDM data model used by XSLT: `<![CDATA[IPMS_TEST_DS_2 & 13]]>` and `IPMS_TEST_DS_2 &amp; 13` are different, but completely synonymous, representations of a text node with string value `IPMS_TEST_DS_2 & 13`. An XSLT stylesheet cannot distinguish them.

There's a processor called LEXEV from Andrew Welch that allows CDATA to be represented in the XDM data model. I've forgotten the details but it uses something like a processing instruction `<?CDATA IPMS_TEST_DS_2 & 13?>`. You could use a similar technique in your SAX filter. Of course that wouldn't be distinguishable from an actual processing instruction named "CDATA".

Comment: thanks for sharing Lib info. but currently, I am processing data using VBA(Visual Basic Application). & I don't know whether LEXEV can be directly handled with VBA / I need to preprocess XML outside VBA.

Comment: You tagged the question "saxon" which confused me.